# Override rpmbuild build location when called from command line

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface, package, rpm

I am making some config packages which are built by Jenkins, then checked out whenever they are needed. The package itself is built and runs fine. My problem right now is the directories that rpmbuild uses for actually building the project. When I call rpmbuild SPECS/package.spec from my working directory, rpmbuild makes a new directory at `/home/user/rpmbuild`. This was fine when I was running tests but I would rather that I just be able to build from whatever file it is called from for the Jenkins process.

I see online people saying to make a `~/.rpmmacros` file to overwrite the `$_topdir` variable. That approach isn't really working for the Jenkins build. Is there some way to simply call rpmbuild and build in the current directory? The structure is all there and it would work better for what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just override `_topdir` directly.

```
rpmbuild -D '_topdir /new/value/for/_topdir'
```

or

```
rpmbuild --define='_topdir /new/value/for/_topdir'
```

those should be identical but I've learned that they aren't always for some reason (and in quick tests `rpm -D '_topdir /opt/tnstmp' --showrc | grep _topdir` doesn't show the modified value but `rpm --define '_topdir /opt/tnstmp' --showrc | grep _topdir` did).

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I had such trouble finding this.